# How to I group by date while splitting multi-day records into multiples?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb collection that has the `processName`, `start` and `stop` fields. Each document thus describes a process that has occurred during a time interval. Each time interval can range from minutes to months, and there can be multiples.

I need to find out the total time each process ran each day. That, I think, requires splitting a process which ran for, say, 30 days, into 30 records, and then grouping per day per processName. Ideally, I wouldn't count processes running simultaneously twice, but if it's very hard to do, I can sacrifice that for the sake of readability.

Comment: Would you show some example documents and the desired output?

Comment: something like `{date: '2022-10-01', processName: 'myCoolProcess', totalDurationHrs: 23.1}`

Answer (score 2):

One option is:

1. Create a list of dates according to the days difference
2. Use `$zip` to create array of timestamps for each day
3. `$unwind`
4. Calculate each document's `key` using `$dateToString` and working `minutes` using `$dateDiff`
5. Group and format

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$set: {
      days: {$map: {
          input: {$range: [1,
            {$add: [{$dateDiff: {startDate: "$start", endDate: "$stop", unit: "day"}}, 1]}]},
          in: {
            $dateAdd: {startDate: {$dateTrunc: {date: "$start", unit: "day"}},
              unit: "day",
              amount: "$$this"
          }}
      }}
  }},
  {$project: {
    _id: 0, 
    processName: 1, 
    timestamp: {$zip: {
        inputs: [
          {$concatArrays: [["$start"], "$days"]}, 
          {$concatArrays: ["$days", ["$stop"]]}
        ]
    }}
  }},
  {$unwind: "$timestamp"},
  {$project: {
      processName: 1,
      key: {$dateToString: {
          date: {$dateTrunc: {date: {$first: "$timestamp"}, unit: "day"}},
          format: "%Y-%m-%d"
      }},
      minutes: {$dateDiff: {
          startDate: {$first: "$timestamp"},
          endDate: {$last: "$timestamp"},
          unit: "minute"
      }}
  }},
  {$group: {
      _id: {processName: "$processName", key: "$key"},
      totalDurationHrs: {$sum: "$minutes"}
  }},
  {$project: {
    _id: 0, 
    totalDurationHrs: {$round: [{$divide: ["$totalDurationHrs", 60]}, 1]}, 
    date: "$_id.key", 
    processName: "$_id.processName"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iru5CSi5AUY)

Comment: Wow, thank you!! You said "one option". Could you name some others?

Comment: This is pretty awesome!  I think you may wish to convert your `{$sum: "$minutes"}` to hours.

Comment: Fixed according to @rickhg12hs comment. Thanks rickhg12hs, sharp as always :)